# ValueError: shapes (2,) and (1,1) not aligned: 2 (dim 0) != 1 (dim 0)

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

```
import numpy as np

# Define the quadratic function
def quadratic_function(x):
    return x ** 2

# Define the neural network class
class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self):
        self.weights = np.random.randn(2)
        self.bias = np.random.randn()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = np.reshape(x, (-1, 1))  # Reshape x to be a column vector
        return np.dot(self.weights, x) + self.bias

    def backward(self, x, y, learning_rate):
        loss_grad = 2 * (self.forward(x) - y) * x
        bias_grad = 2 * (self.forward(x) - y)
        self.weights -= learning_rate * loss_grad
        self.bias -= learning_rate * bias_grad

# Training the neural network
def train_neural_network(neural_network, x_train, y_train, num_epochs, learning_rate):
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for x, y in zip(x_train, y_train):
            neural_network.backward(x, y, learning_rate)

# Define the input values and target values for training
x_train = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
y_train = quadratic_function(x_train)

# Create an instance of the neural network
neural_net = NeuralNetwork()

# Train the neural network
train_neural_network(neural_net, x_train, y_train, num_epochs=100, learning_rate=0.01)

# Test the neural network
x_test = np.array([5, 6, 7])
y_test = quadratic_function(x_test)
predictions = neural_net.forward(x_test)

# Print the results
print("Target Values:", y_test)
print("Predictions:", predictions)



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-9b3419710a08> in <cell line: 37>()
     35 
     36 # Train the neural network
---> 37 train_neural_network(neural_net, x_train, y_train, num_epochs=100, learning_rate=0.01)
     38 
     39 # Test the neural network

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py in dot(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: shapes (2,) and (1,1) not aligned: 2 (dim 0) != 1 (dim 0)
```

Comment: Well, your batch tuple (x,y) consists of scalars and not vectors. Thus your reshape call is completely redundant. But in future please check this yourself by printing the variables in question.